# Made Custom UITableViewCell -- Now UITableView Is Not Scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Created an empty `xib`.
Created a class that overrides `UITableViewCell` (UserCell).

Put in a custom pieces of logic that simply format some strings for display and connected the two labels in `IB`.

My view controller owns an `UITableView`. I've set the view controller as the data source.
Here's how I go about populating it with my custom cells.

(did: http://www.highoncoding.com/Videos/823_Creating_a_Custom_UITableViewCell.aspx)

```
-(UserCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UserCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Users Table"];

    if (!cell) {
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UserCell class]]) {
                cell = (UserCell*) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    [cell setUserNameText:[[[_userDataManager getUsers] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name ]];
    [cell setNumberLabelText:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

For some reason, I am not able to scroll. In `viewDidLoad:` I'm printing `scrollEnabled` on my table view. It's "1".

Haven't had this trouble until I tried putting in a custom `UITableViewCell`. :(

Thanks SO for any advice! :D

EDIT: Custom cell code.

```
#import "UserCell.h"

@implementation UserCell

@synthesize textLabel, numberLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(void) setNumberLabelText:(NSInteger)text {
    self.numberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"# %d", text];
}

-(void) setUserNameText:(NSString*)text {
    self.userNameLabel.text = text;
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the custom cell

Comment: Not sure what happened. Don't think I changed anything.... I just deployed it to my phone and it scrolled there fine. Back to iPhone sim and now it's scrolling ok :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question as answered (I'm a derp sometimes)

I haven't done much iOS stuff using a trackpad. Seems like I was expecting two finger scrolling to "scroll" on the simulator. It does not!

A heads up for anyone else having this issue.